# How does double XP work?

Tags: battlefield-3

Some weekends, Battlefield 3 has "double XP".  I would expect it to either double your base-XP or your total XP, but that appears to not be the case.

For instance, in the last game I played, I got 4005 base XP, and 8000-some total XP.  My "double XP bonus" was 900.

**How is the double XP bonus calculated?**

Comment: It could be double for capping points or planting/defuse. I would contact EA (for all the good that will do) or dice and see how they tackle your question.

Comment: can you provide a link to the match?

Comment: @Novarg: Anyone can try playing a match.  It's double-XP weekend, and the double XP bonus is **never** equal to your base-XP

Answer (score 3):

Just played a game with double exp activated.

At the end of the game I got:

- 3460 jet score
- *Air Warfare* medal (10k score)
- A few ribbons total worth 1500 score
- **A double exp bonus** of 11500 score.

So I'd say that double experience gives you experience for medals and ribbons only.

[Here](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/show/1/67714564/281536208/) is the *Battlelog* report. As you see, my *Award Score* is twice of what I should have had.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading somewhere that you do not get any Double XP from the base XP from in game actions, but from the award XP, such as medals and ribbons. That's usually why you'll see Operation Metro filled with medpacks.

Answer (score 0):

All points during game are doubled.

Battlefield 3 never shows all points at end of game. It only shows awards such as ribbons, medals, unlocks, etc. You will never see individual points earned for kills, spotting, head shots, flag capping, etc. at end of game report.

Thus, when the end of game report shows bonus XP it only shows it in relation to items that are already shown at end of game report.

It may be confusing but it aligns with how they use their reporting system in game.

But all points earned in game are doubled. If (and this is a big if) you finish the game. As the doubling only occurs on completed games. So if you play a game during 2XP and you don't get to the point of the game calculating the 2XP then you will not earn the 2XP. (though you will still earn all points awarded during the game)

Hope that helps a few? But anyone posting that 2XP does not double all points earned in game are supplying incorrect information.

Comment: This would make sense, but I haven't seen anything to support this yet.

Answer (score -1):

You get double the normal points that you would when killing, planting, defusing etc.

Comment: Sorry, what is "etc."?  I know it's not **all** things that you get points for before the end of the game, because that would be my base XP - and as I mentioned in the question, my base-xp was 4005, but the "double XP bonus" was only 900.

Comment: Because double XP is awarded at the end of round screen you will need to finish the round in order to receive the double XP bonus. If you quit early or disconnect, you will still earn any points or awards you got, but not the double XP bonus. Like,when you finish a game without double XP, you get a bonus at the end if every round/game. So the double XP bonus is basically just the end game bonus ,doubled.

Comment: This website helped me when I played BF3. Hope it helps you too.      [link] http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654489820350283/

Comment: I did finish the whole game, and got the double XP bonus, as mentioned in the question.  But it is **not** equal to your base XP from that round!

Comment: It's not the base XP.. It's the in game bonus, like the little extras you get for the game. Look on th link it tells you how the XP is calculated. It's the ADDITIONAL points you earn for the game.